# PyBind11 destructor not invoked?

Tags: python, c++, destructor, pybind11

I have a `c++` class wrapped with `PyBind11`. The issue is: when the `Python` script ends the `c++` `destructor` is not being automatically invoked.  This causes an untidy exit because networking resources need to be released by the destructor.

As a work-around it is necessary to explicitly delete the `Python` object, but I don't understand why!

Please could someone explain what is wrong here and how to get the `destructor` called automatically when the `Python` object is garbage collected?

Pybind11 binding code:

```
py::class_<pcs::Listener>(m, "listener")
    .def(py::init<const py::object &, const std::string &, const std::string &, const std::string &, const std::string &, const std::set<std::string> &, const std::string & , const bool & , const bool & >(), R"pbdoc(
    Monitors network traffic.

    When a desired data source is detected a client instance is connected to consume the data stream.

    Reconstructs data on receipt, like a jigsaw.  Makes requests to fill any gaps.  Verifies the data as sequential.

    Data is output by callback to Python.  Using the method specified in the constructor, which must accept a string argument.
)pbdoc");
```

In Python:

```
#Function to callback
def print_string(str):
    print("Python; " + str)

lstnr = listener(print_string, 'tcp://127.0.0.1:9001', clientCertPath, serverCertPath, proxyCertPath, desiredSources, 'time_series_data', enableCurve, enableVerbose)

#Run for a minute
cnt = 0
while cnt < 60:
    cnt += 1
    time.sleep(1)

#Need to call the destructor explicity for some reason    
del lstnr
```

Comment: Please see this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38228170/c-destructor-calling-of-boostpython-wrapped-objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So some years later I fixed this issue by enabling [Python context manager](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#context-managers) `with` support by adding `__enter__` and `__exit__` method handling to my [PyBind11](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html#) code:

```
py::class_<pcs::Listener>(m, "listener")
.def(py::init<const py::object &, const std::string &, const std::string &, const std::string &, const std::string &, const std::set<std::string> &, const std::string & , const bool & , const bool & >(), R"pbdoc(
    Monitors network traffic.

    When a desired data source is detected a client instance is connected to consume the data stream.
    
    Specify 'type' as 'string' or 'market_data' to facilitate appropriate handling of BarData or string messages.

    Reconstructs data on receipt, like a jigsaw.  Makes requests to fill any gaps.  Verifies the data as sequential.

    Data is output by callback to Python.  Using the method specified in the constructor, which must accept a string argument.
)pbdoc")
.def("__enter__", &pcs::Listener::enter, R"pbdoc(
    Python 'with' context manager support.
)pbdoc")    
.def("__exit__", &pcs::Listener::exit, R"pbdoc(
    Python 'with' context manager support.
)pbdoc");
```

Added corresponding functions to the C++ class, like so:

```
//For Python 'with' context manager
auto enter(){std::cout << "Context Manager: Enter" << std::endl; return py::cast(this); }//returns a pointer to this object for 'with'....'as' python functionality
auto exit(py::handle type, py::handle value, py::handle traceback){ std::cout << "Context Manager: Exit: " << type << " " << value << " " << traceback <<  std::endl; }
```

N.B.

1. The returned pointer value from `enter()` is important to the `as` functionality in a `with`....`as` statement.
2. The parameters passed to `exit(py::handle type, py::handle value, py::handle traceback)` are useful debugging info.

Python usage:

```
with listener(cb, endpoint, clientCertPath, serverCertPath, proxyCertPath, desiredSources, type, enableCurve, enableVerbose):
cnt = 0
while cnt < 10:
    cnt += 1
    time.sleep(1)
```

The Python context manager now calls the destructor on the C++ object thus smoothly releasing the networking resources.

Answer (score 0):

As was mentioned in a comment, the proximate cause of this behavior is the Python garbage collector:  When the reference counter for an object gets to zero, the garbage collector *may* destroy the object (and thereby invoke the c++ destructor) but it doesn't *have to do it at that moment*.

This idea is elaborated more fully in the answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/38238013/790979

As also mentioned in the above link, if you've got clean up to do at the end of an object's lifetime in Python, a nice solution is [context management](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/context_managers.html), where you'd define `__enter__` and `__exit__` in the object's wrapper (either in pybind11 or in Python itself), have `__exit__` release the networking resources, and then, in the Python client code, something like:

```
with listener(print_string, 'tcp://127.0.0.1:9001', clientCertPath, serverCertPath, proxyCertPath, desiredSources, 'time_series_data', enableCurve, enableVerbose) as lstnr:
    # Run for a minute
    cnt = 0
    while cnt < 60:
        cnt += 1
        time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer & explanation @charleslparker.  Though I've still not solved the issue because I've struggled to find examples & documentation about how to implement `__enter__` and `__exit__` in the `PyBind11` binding code.

Answer (score 0):

GoFaster's solution above is helpful and the correct approach but I just wanted to clarify and correct their assertion that

> The Python context manager now calls the destructor on the C++ object thus smoothly releasing the networking resources

This is simply not true. The context manager only guarantees that `__exit__` will be called, not that any destructor will be called. Let me demonstrate - here's a managed resource implemented in C++:

```cpp
class ManagedResource
{
public:
    ManagedResource(int i) : pi(std::make_unique<int>(i))
    {
        py::print("ManagedResource ctor");
    }

    ~ManagedResource()
    {
        py::print("ManagedResource dtor");
    }

    int get() const { return *pi; }

    py::object enter()
    {
        py::print("entered context manager");
        return py::cast(this);
    }

    void exit(py::handle type, py::handle value, py::handle traceback)
    {
        // release resources
        // pi.reset();
        py::print("exited context manager");
    }

private:
    std::unique_ptr<int> pi;
};
```

the python bindings:

```cpp
    py::class_<ManagedResource>(m, "ManagedResource")
    .def(py::init<int>())
    .def("get", &ManagedResource::get)
    .def("__enter__", &ManagedResource::enter, R"""(
        Enter context manager.
    )""")
    .def("__exit__", &ManagedResource::exit, R"""(
        Leave context manager.
    )""");
```

and some python test code (note that the code above *doesn't* (yet) release the resource in `__exit__`):

```py
def f():
    with ManagedResource(42) as resource1:
        print(f"get = {resource1.get()}")
    print(f"hey look I'm still here {resource1.get()}") # not destroyed


if __name__ == "__main__":
    f()
    print("end")
```

which produces:

```
ManagedResource ctor
entered context manager
get = 42
exited context manager
hey look I'm still here 42
ManagedResource dtor
end
```

so the resource is constructed, acquiring memory, and accessed within the context manager. All good so far. However the memory is still accessible outside the context manager (and before the destuctor is called, which is decided by the python runtime and outside our control unless we force it with `del`, which completely defeats the point of the context manager.

But we didnt actually release the resource in `__exit__`.  If you uncomment `pi.reset()` in that function, you'll get this:

```
ManagedResource ctor
entered context manager
get = 42
exited context manager
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

this time, when you call `get()` outside the context manager, the `ManagedResource` object itself is still very much not destructed, but the resource inside it **has** been released,

And there's even more danger: if you create a `ManagedResource` outside a `with` block, you'll leak resource as `__exit__` will never get called. To fix this, you'll need to defer acquiring the resources from the constructor to the `__enter__` method, as well as putting checks that the resource exists in `get`.

In short, the morals of this story are:

- you can't rely on when/where python objects are destructed, even for context managers
- you *can* control acquisition and release of resources *within* a context manager
- resources should be acquired in the `__enter__` method, not in the constructor
- resources should be released in the `__exit__` method, not is the destructor
- you should put sufficient guards around access to the resources

A context-managed object is not an RAII resource itself, but a wrapper around a RAII resource.

Comment: Thanks for your insightful comments and best practice suggestions.  I added `delete this;` into my `exit()` function on the c++ side to self-destruct the instance.  I noticed that this does, of course, directly invoke the c++ destructor logic which in my case releases resources, however I also notice the object lives on and a second invocation of the destructor follows later which must be coming from the Python side.  I suspect that `return py::cast(this);` returns a shared pointer to the object facilitating this longevity behaviour.

Comment: `delete this;` is for heap-allocated memory only so may invoke UB, you probably meant  `this->~listener();`  but you've already spotted that this leads to 2 destructor calls. In my example it's only the member variable inside the `ManagedResource` class is released in `exit`, not the class itself. You might need to put your `listener` class in a wrapper class.

Comment: Silly me, yes `this->~Listener();` added to the `exit()` function invokes the destructor but also results in a later second destructor call.